# String date property of object is deserialized to another format even though it should remain unchanged

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

I am trying to deserialize `Customer` objects from a string representing a `JArray`. One of the properties is a Date as string:

```
public class Customer: ICustomer
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = 0)]
    public string CreationDate{ get; set; }
}
```

In the JSON, the `CreationDate` is set to `"2015-12-31T00:00:00+01:00"`, which is the exact string I expect to find in my deserialized object.

I have written the following to deserialize the objects :

```
protected Collection<Customer> GetCustomers(string jsonText)
{
    var jobject = JArray.Parse(jsonText);
    var allClients = new Collection<Customer>()
    var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer
    { 
        DateParseHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateParseHandling.None;
    };

    foreach (var child in jobject.Children())
    {
        var customer= child.ToObject<Customer>(jsonSerializer);
        allClients.Add(customer);
    }
    return allClients;
}
```

However, the value of the `CreationDate` in my deserialized `Customer` is equal to `"12/31/2015 00:00:00"`, as if the `DateParseHandling` attribute is ignored. Why?

Comment: CreationDate is an string so there's no date handling at all.